# how to save an entity with a DiscriminatorValue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I have two entities `User` and `Candidat`, where `Candidat` extends the class `User`, as following :

**User entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_USER",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=2)

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(name="UC",value=Candidat.class)
})

@XmlSeeAlso({Candidat.class})
public class User implements Serializable {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codeUser;
//other code ...
```

**Candidat entity :**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("UC")
@XmlType(name = "UC")
public class Candidat extends User {
    private String codeMassar;
```

and to save a new Candidat I call this repository method :

```
candidatRepository.save()
```

from :

```
public interface CandidatRepository extends JpaRepository<Candidat, String> {

}
```

This is my rest service that calls the save method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidats", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Candidat saveCandidat(@RequestBody Candidat candidat) throws Exception {
    return candidatMetier.saveCandidat(candidat);
}
```

The problem is when I want to save a new Candidat as following :

```
{
  "username": "User",
  "password": "123456",
  "email": "user@gmail.com"
}
```

I get an error saying :

> Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected
>   FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for
>   class org.capvalue.fme.domain.Candidat)

What I understand from it that I have to specify the type in the JSON object I'm sending, but I don't think that's necessary because I save a new `Candidat` which has the `@DiscriminatorValue("UC")`, so when its `save` in the `User` table it will be saved with `type='UC'` automatically.

how can I solve this ?

Comment: Try to comment `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I understand from it that I have to specify the type in the json
>   object I'm sending

Since you've added the `@JsonTypeInfo`, you should specify the actual class of object instances using the `type` field. For instance, if you set the `type` field to `UC`, Jackson will create an instance of `Candidat` class.

> but I dont think that's necessary because I save a new Candidat which
>   has the @DiscriminatorValue("UC") so when its save in the User table
>   it will be saved with type='UC' automatically.

`@DiscriminatorValue` is going to be handled by your JPA provider. On the contrary, `@JsonTypeInfo` is a Jackson concept, so No! You can't expect your JPA `@DiscriminatorValue` helps Jackson to determine the actual type of the object instances.

You should either send `type` information in your JSON representation or remove `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` from your `User` class. I guess removing the Jackson type annotations is the better approach, since you're using the actual subclasses in:

```
public Candidat saveCandidat(@RequestBody Candidat candidat) { ... }
```

Also, try to define some *DTO*s and return them as your REST endpoint return values. One advantage of this approach is that your Jackson and JPA metadatas are separated, hence you would avoid these problems.

Comment: Thanks now i understand the problem, so in this case can't I simply specify the type in the service code without specifying it from the client side ?

Comment: Yes, you should do that. Imo you're not using `JsonTyeInfo` quite right and its better to remove it.

Comment: I couldn't find I way to specify the type in the service code when I save a new candidate since this field is presented only in database.

Comment: Remove the `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`, pass your current json and save the `candidat`. JPA will set the appropriate discriminator column value based your type.